# PHP SQL / Table/alias not unique

Tags: php, sql

I need some help/advice on how to use this sql to update the table I need.

The sql looks like this:

```
UPDATE firme_ro
INNER JOIN z_icap_minim ON firme_ro.CUI=z_icap_minim.CUI
INNER JOIN firme_ro ON z_icap_minim.judet_Id <> firme_ro.judeteSiruta_Id AND z_icap_minim.cui = firme_ro.cui
SET firme_ro.NumarInregistrare=z_icap_minim.Nrreg
WHERE firme_ro.StariFirme_Id=1
```

The sql is generating error code:

> Not unique table/alias: 'firme_ro'

Should I be using an "alias"? I am trying to run this in PHP my admin so any advice/help would be appreciated!

Comment: Tag dbms. (That UPDATE syntax is product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE firme_ro AS fr1
INNER JOIN z_icap_minim AS zim ON fr1.CUI=zim.CUI
INNER JOIN firme_ro AS fr2 ON zim.judet_Id <> fr2.judeteSiruta_Id AND zim.cui = fr2.cui
SET fr1.NumarInregistrare=zim.Nrreg
WHERE fr1.StariFirme_Id=1
```

Comment: Worked perfectlly! Tyvm for help! "Alias" all the way!

Comment: Please explain your solution to all other SO fans ;)

Comment: This is all about uniqueness, so used Alias. It was showing error, as OP was joining the same table which was getting updated. Please let me know whether you still have confusion on my solution.